# ClassNotFoundException - class isn't supposed to exist

Tags: android, android-studio

Based on the error message, there is an error inflating `foo.barscratch.ItemView` because it doesn't exist. The thing is, it's not supposed to exist. I don't know what is referencing it.

Originally I copied this file from another project and renamed it to `foo.bar.BazItemView`.

Nothing should be calling `foo.barscratch.ItemView` but a search for the string "scratch" or word "ItemView" in my project turns up nothing. What's going on here? I just want to get rid if whatever is calling this class.

```
01-15 21:58:28.073  11348-11348/foo.bar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: foo.bar, PID: 11348
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class foo.barscratch.ItemView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at foo.bar.BazItemView.inflate(BazItemView.java:17)
            at foo.bar.BazItemAdapter.getView(BazItemAdapter.java:18)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "foo.barscratch.ItemView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/foo.bar-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at foo.bar.BazItemView.inflate(BazItemView.java:17)
            at foo.bar.BazItemAdapter.getView(BazItemAdapter.java:18)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed
```

ItemView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<foo.bar.BazItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
</foo.bar.BazItemView>
```

item_view_children.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_imageView"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/item_imageView_contentDescription"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_imageView"
    android:text="title text"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_descriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_imageView"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="description text"
    />

</merge>
```

Comment: Post your code with XML file.

Comment: Probably in layout xmls you are using `foo.barscratch.ItemView` as class name

Comment: @Dhaval Sorry, but which XML file?

Comment: It is getting it from xml, can you post that too?

Comment: Have you properly checked that your view is under this `foo.bar` folder?

Comment: @Piyush - All java files are under `foo.bar`

Answer (score 0):

Accordring to the exception it seems that you are referencing some custom view (the `ItemView` class) in your layout (xml) file on line 3. Check again your layout file if everything is OK with it.

Comment: I have six xml files in the Layout folder. I've posted the two that weren't auto generated. I'm still not seeing where the `ItemView` class is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure .. But you can try checking memory management for that specific view.

There's possibility to get inflate exception while memory exceeds specific limits while rendering a view.

OR

Check if custom view you are trying to show does not exist.

Let me know if that works for you so that I can keep this stuff in my mind for future reference.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Reload Project.

I searched again for the word ItemView and found one reference to ItemView.java in the workspace.xml file. I commented the line out and Android Studio asked me if I wanted to reload the project. I said OK. Errors gone.

Incidentally, I uncommented out the line afterwards and upon reload, the errors did not return.

I suspect this may be a bug with Android Studio. At one point I dragged ItemView.java from an old project to this one. A dialog popped up asking about linking to an external project. I hit cancel, but despite hitting cancel the IDE attempted to do some refactoring and reported read-only errors twice.

Thanks all who offered assistance!